# How can I make the bottom border grow from the left side and minimize to the right side?

Tags: css

I need to create a hover affect for an element that would basically look like how this looks:

https://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/eNNdme

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="cool-link" href="#">A cool link</a></li>
    <li><a class="cool-link" href="#">A cool link</a></li>
    <li><a class="cool-link" href="#">A cool link</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.cool-link {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.cool-link::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000;
    transition: width .3s;
}

.cool-link:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

But, instead of the border minimizing back to where it came from, it should minimize to the other side. So basically, it should look like the border came from the left on hover and disappeared to the right when no hovered anymore.

Can't figure out what could cause that affect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 2 hours of trying, I found a solution. If I understand what you mean, the code snippet below is what you want:

```css
li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.cool-link {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cool-link::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  background: #002;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
}

.cool-link:hover::after {
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
     <li><a class="cool-link" href="#">A cool link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I've needed! If I get that right, the main "secret" here is the transform origin right? Appreciate the effort to figure that out

Comment: @Tsabary yes, transform origin is the main "secret". My pleasure

Answer (score 2):

Using a CSS animation on the pseudo element you have lots of flexibility on how the line looks. Here's a simple example of it growing from left to right then disappearing from left to right. You could have it repeating, or reversing order and so on. I set the overall effect to 1 second just to make it more noticeable.

```css
li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.cool-link {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.cool-link::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: black;
}

.cool-link:hover::after {
    position: relative;
    width: 0;
    animation: underline 1s;
}
@keyframes underline {
  0% {
      width: 0;
      left:0;
  }
  50% {
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
  }
  100% {
      width: 0;
      left: 100%;      
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a class="cool-link" href="#">A cool link</a></li>
    <li><a class="cool-link" href="#">A cool link</a></li>
    <li><a class="cool-link" href="#">A cool link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's not exactly what I've needed (Ramin go it right) but that's an awesome example nonetheless

Comment: Ah, yes I'd misinterpreted what was required - but thanks for looking.  @Ramin s solution  is neat.